# A way to prepare suet dumplings ahead of time?

Tags: reheating, dumplings

An English-style beef stew is a great dish to prepare/freeze ahead of time, and heat when it's needed. But one of its delights is suet dumplings, which are normally cooked floating in the stew while it heats in an oven, for about 10-15 minutes covered, to steam, and then uncovered for about the last 10 minutes of cooking time, to brown on top. This does not make for quick service.

Is there a way to prepare them ahead of time, and achieve something like the quality they have when cooked by this slower method?